# Passing data from the database to a blade view using a controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I found several ways to do what I need to do, the first way was using the rounting using the web.php file. But according to serveral posts this creates vulnerabilities in the application. So I found out the correct usage is with a controller that manages the database queries.

I created a controller, named EventsController and put this into it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $events = DB::table('eventaries')->select('id','coursname','start', 'end', 'category')->get();

        return view('components.course-list')->with('eventaries', $events);
    }
}
```

the blade is inside the folder: `/resources/views/components/course-list.blade.php`

Inside the blade I use this code:

```
<div class="px-6 py-20">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <!-- Course List -->

        {{ $events->coursname}}


    </div>
</div>
```

But I get the error:

```
Undefined variable $events (View: D:\laragon\www\censored\resources\views\components\course-list.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `with` method on a view the first argument (key) becomes the name of the variable in the view and the second argument (value) becomes it's value.

This means you need to use `$eventaries` in your view instead of `$events` or rename the key in your controller `return view('components.course-list')->with('events', $events);`.

Also, I'm not sure about defining the action directly in the routes file causes vulnerabilities. I just think that the routes file, which is often the first entry point for developers when exploring a Laravel app, becomes hard to read/manage.

Comment: It still shows Undefined variable $eventaries (View: D:\laragon\www\censored\resources\views\components\course-list.blade.php) Is is possible to use folders inside the return view or what else could create this issue?

Comment: Even though the `resources/views/components` directory is generally used to store Blade component views, it actually does not matter and should work. Is there any other code in the view that might unset the variable by accident?

Comment: no, the blade I posted is all of its content. I load it into another blade using @component, as it is used inside multiple pages and I want to make it more dynamic. But I dont think that this could cause this issue, as the root issue is inside the original blade that I posted.

Comment: When you do a `dd` on the view, do you see `eventaries` as a key in the `data` array of the view? `dd(view('components.course-list')->with('eventaries', $events));`

Answer (score 0):

->with('eventaries', $events) means that you are passing the value of $events as eventaries. So in the blade you need to access it using $eventaries instead. So now blade code would be:

```
    <div class="px-6 py-20">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <!-- Course List -->

        {{ $eventaries->coursname}}


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given 'eventaries' as the name for events. So you can only access it with $eventaries within the view, not as events.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing to the view the value using the "with" method, and it does it like a value/key pair (->with($key, $value)). In your case you declare it like

```
return view('components.course-list')->with('eventaries', $events);
```

so, in the view you can access the value through the $eventaries, not the $events. Also, the query result is a collection and you will need to loop it to get each item

```
<div class="px-6 py-20">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <!-- Course List -->
        @foreach($eventaries as $event)
        {{ $event->coursename }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**What caused the issue?**
The issue of this question was created because the router was never accessing the controller I created. I added the following code to my router to access the controller:

```
Route::get('/kursangebote/{course}', ['App\Http\Controllers\EventaryController', 'index'])->name('course.list-list');
```

In there I added the logic I wanted.

```
['App\Http\Controllers\EventaryController', 'index']
```

`App\Http\Controllers\EventaryController` is the controller I use, and `index` the function inside the controller I need to call. It might be a better Idea to use Eloquent for this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent